# How to shift all 2D array values (wrap them around) in F#?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, f#

I am trying to create a program which moves a 2D array in four directions. The example below is moving to the right.

```
1 0 0    0 1 0
0 2 0 -> 0 0 2
0 0 3    3 0 0
```

I really don't know what I'm doing, here is the code so far. What is the best way to achieve this, please?

```
open System

let mutable array = [| [| 1; 0; 0 |]
                       [| 0; 2; 0 |]
                       [| 0; 0; 3 |] |]

printfn "%A" array

for i in 0 .. (array.[*].Length - 1) do
    for j in 0 .. (array.[*].[*].Length - 1) do
        array.[i].[j] <- array.[(i + 1)].[(j + 1)]

printfn "%A" array

Console.Read() |> ignore
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code for the right rotation is a good sketch, but there are a few things:

- If you are using arrays of arrays, then you need to get the length using `array.[i].Length`
- You will need to save the value of the last element (to do the rotation)
- You will need to iterate over indices from the right (if you want to move values to the right)

Here is a piece of code that does this for the right rotation:

```
for i in 0 .. array.Length - 1 do
  // Save the last element in the array so that we can rotate it
  let first = array.[i].[array.[i].Length-1]
  // Iterate over elements from the rigth and put the value of
  // element at index j into element at index j+1 (to the right)
  for j in array.[i].Length - 2 .. -1 .. 0 do
    array.[i].[j+1] <- array.[i].[j]
  // We overwrote the last element in the array, so now we need to
  // use the value we saved earlier for the first element
  array.[i].[0] <- first
```

The notation `end .. -1 .. start` in the nested loop is used to iterate from larger values of indices to smaller.